# VBA Duplicate Condition Met Before Running Macro

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am trying to manage duplicates on an Excel sheet by having the duplicate cells' font turn red. I decided to use a macro to check for duplicates, code below. It works, but I have one small issue:

When I type in a new cell within the range, it automatically turn red even if there is no duplicate, unless I run the macro again then it corrects itself. I would like for it to stay black in the first instance and show up red only when it is a duplicate-- after running the macro.

```
Sub Duplicate()
Dim rngData As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim cell2 As Range

Set rngData = Range("P3:P19, P56:P58, P39:P42, P21:P25, P27:P37, P39:P42, P39:P42, P44:P54, M25:M76, B69:B77, B66:E67, B51:B64, H44:H47, D44:D47, H42, H33:H40, D33:D42, H31, D28:D31, H28:H29, D5:D8" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)

rngData.Font.Color = vbBlack

For Each cell In rngData
    If cell.Font.Color = vbBlack Then
        For Each cell2 In rngData
            If cell = cell2 And cell.Address <> cell2.Address Then
                cell.Font.Color = vbRed
                cell2.Font.Color = vbRed
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next


Set rngData = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a Worksheet Change event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rngData As Range
Application.EnableEvents = False
On Error GoTo getout
Set rngData = Range("P3:P19, P56:P58, P39:P42, P21:P25, P27:P37, P39:P42, P39:P42, P44:P54, M25:M76, B69:B77, B66:E67, B51:B64, H44:H47, D44:D47, H42, H33:H40, D33:D42, H31, D28:D31, H28:H29, D5:D8" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)

If Not Intersect(Target, rngData) Is Nothing Then
    Duplicate
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub

getout:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Put this in the code sheet for the worksheet on which the data is located.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that two empty cells match than when you run this macro all empty cells will have red color font. So add `cell.Value <> ""` to you If condition

Comment: Alternatively this could be solved by doing `For Each cell In rngData.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)`

Comment: Using the suggestion by @Taelsin allows the code to run faster than added another statement to the If condition